# Python removing duplicates in a list

Tags: python, list

I want to remove duplicated in a python list in a way that allows me to alter another corresponding list in the same way. In the below example `original` is the list I want to de-duplicate. Each element in `key` that shares the same index as original corresponds to each other:

```
original = [a,a,a,3,4,5,b,2,b]
key      = [h,f,g,5,e,6,u,z,t]
```

So I want to remove duplicates in `original` such that whatever element I delete from original I delete the corresponding element (of the same index) in `key`. Results I want:

```
deduplicated_original = [a,3,4,5,b,2]
deduplicated_key      = [h,5,e,6,u,z]
```

I can get `deduplicated`_original using `list(set(original))` however I cannot get the corresponding `deduplicated_key`

Comment: Is `['g', 5, 'e', 6, 't', 'z']` okay? removal of all but the last?

Comment: Can you please show any attempts you've made? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set) to keep track of duplicates and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over indexes/values of the original list:

```
seen = set()
lst = []

for i, v in enumerate(original):
    if not v in seen:
        lst.append(key[i])
        seen.add(v)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe less elegant, less easy to follow the list revesal, index slicing

the inner list comp walks the input list `org` backwards, asking if there is a prior matching element, if so record the index of this duplicate

```
[len(org) - 1 - i
 for i, e in enumerate(org[::-1]) if e in org[:-i-1]]
```

then the outer list comp uses `.pop()` to modify org, ky as a side effect

nested list comprehension 'dups', a 'one liner' (with line breaks):

```
org = ['a','a','a',3,4,5,'b',2,'b']
ky = ['h','f','g',5,'e',6,'u','z','t']

dups = [(org.pop(di), ky.pop(di))
        for di in [len(org) - 1 - i
                   for i, e in enumerate(org[::-1]) if e in org[:-i-1]]]

org, ky, dups
Out[208]: 
(['a', 3, 4, 5, 'b', 2],
 ['h', 5, 'e', 6, 'u', 'z'],
 [('b', 't'), ('a', 'g'), ('a', 'f')])
```

of course you don't actually have to assign the list comp result to anything to get the side effect of modifying the lists

Answer (score 0):

You can manually get all the indices of duplicates like this:

```
indices = []
existing = set()
for i, item in enumerate(original):
    if item in existing:
        indices.append(i)
    else:
        existing.add(item)
```

and then remove those indices from your `key` list, in reverse because deleting a key changes the indices of further items:

```
for i in reversed(indices):
    del key[i]
```